# CircleCI Heroku Git subtree testing conundrum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, circleci

I am working on an project which runs a Rails backend and a Angularjs web app on the front end. Both the apps are in a main project folder as subdirectories to keep the two in check and I have been using the git subtree push to deploy the Rails app to Heroku from the root folder.

I am now looking to use CircleCI and am having difficulties using this project structure and getting CircleCI to run the correct tests and only deploy the Rails app to Heroku.

I tried the follow in the circle.yml

```
general:
  build_dir: server
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: staging
    commands:
      - git subtree push --prefix server git@heroku.com:app-name-staging.git master
```

This configuration allows me to run the tests that are in the Rails app but will not deploy, coming back with the error "You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree."

```
general:
  build_dir: server
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: staging
    commands:
      - git push git@heroku.com:app-name-staging.git master
```

This gave me the error "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" as Heroku was not detecting the buildpack for the Rails.

I have also tried putting a simple shell script test in the root folder and removing the the build_dir from the circle.yml and it will pass the test and do the subtree push of the Rails app to Heroku, but does not run the tests in the Rails app.

I have two options, one runs the tests of the Rails app but wont deploy only the Rails app to Heroku and the second run tests in the root but not on the actual Rails app but will deploy correctly. 
I am looking for a way to combine these two options so that I am able to run the tests of the Rails app and then deploy only the Rails app to Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having contacted the guys at CircleCi, they helped me figure out the correct command to use which was

```
general:
  build_dir: server
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: staging
    commands:
      - cd .. && git push git@heroku.com:app-name-staging.git master
```

This works like a charm, testing the rails server app then deploying only this app to Heroku